# Windows 10 UWP C# Barcode Sample does not see scanner

Tags: c#, uwp, pointofservice

I've been trying to get my scanner to work in this UWP sample, [Windows-universal-samples/Samples/BarcodeScanner/cs/](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BarcodeScanner/cs). However, my scanner Honeywell Xenon 1900GHD-2 is not found as a valid scanner. The project reports "Barcode scanner not found. Please connect a barcode scanner."

[image]

This particular scanner (Honeywell Xenon 1900G) is listed on the Windows [compatibility list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/barcode-scanner#compatible-hardware), yet doesn't work. I've tried using Honeywell's EZConfig utility to force the scanner into dedicated HID POS mode (I've actually tried all of its available modes) and it makes no difference.

[image]

I'm running Windows 10 Anniversary Update, so it should work as noted in the sample project, Windows 10 Version 1703 is the SDK target.

[image]

Any idea why it's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up testing this on a different machine with the newest insider build and it worked correctly. I suspect that installing UPOS 1.12 on my development machine might be what caused this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into something similar recently, and I found this 
[barcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGnO8.png) while going through Honeywell Voyager 1200g manual. After scanning this, the device is being recognized as a POS Barcode Scanner in my [Device Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNw1w.png). And the UWP Barcode Sample solution was able to recognize the device as well. Apart from that, make sure that PointOfService is mentioned in the Device Capabilities in the appxmanifest file.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'll give the barcode a try. I already verified that the PointOfService reference was present in the manifest. It was already included as part of the sample.

Comment: I tried the barcode this morning, and while it did do something, which was to remove the USB HID keyboard from device manager.  It didn't seem to make a difference in the UWP barcode sample app. Thanks for the suggestion.